# SQL IN() operator with condition inside

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got table with few numbers inside (or even empty): `@states table (value int)`
And I need to make SELECT from another table with WHERE clause by definite column.
This column's values must match one of `@states` numbers or if  `@states` is empty then accept all values (like there is no WHERE condition for this column).
So I tried something like this:

```
select *
from dbo.tbl_docs docs
where 
docs.doc_state in(iif(exists(select 1 from @states), (select value from @states), docs.doc_state))
```

Unfortunately iif() can't return subquery resulting dataset. I tried different variations with iif() and CASE but it wasn't successful. How to make this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from dbo.tbl_docs docs
where 
(
  (select count(*) from @states) > 0 
       AND 
   docs.doc_state in(select value from @states)
)
OR
(
  (select count(*) from @states)=0 
      AND 1=1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a left join do?

```
declare @statesCount int;

select @statesCount = count(1) from @states;

select 
 docs.*
from dbo.tbl_docs docs
left join @states s on docs.doc_state = s.value
where s.value is not null or @statesCount = 0;
```

In general, whenever your query contains sub-queries, you should stop for five minutes, and think hard about whether you really need a sub-query at all.

And if you've got a server capable of doing that, in many cases it might be better to preprocess the input parameters first, or perhaps use constructs such as MS SQL's `with`.

Comment: A left join returns all row in docs.   This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from dbo.tbl_docs docs
where exists (select 1 from @states where value = doc_state) 
or not exists (select 1 from @state)
```